# Is it possible to emulate v-model input behaviour on a paragraph tag?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

## Solution:

Thanks to @Jeronimas I figured out how to use `dynamic components` in vue. Basically you create a `child component` that switches between `<p>`and `<input>` tags, depending on `props`. You have to use `<component>` element for this, because it's an inherent vue component to manage `dynamic components`.

**`child`**:

```
<template>
  <input v-if="input" type="text" value="hello world">
  <p v-else>hello world</p>
</template>


<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    input: Boolean
})
//emit input when form is submitted...
</script>
```

**`parent`**:

```
<template>
    <component :is="p" :input="true"/>
</template>


<script setup>
import p from './p.vue'
</script>
```

Vue is awesome <3.

## Original Question:

Is it possible to input text into `<p>` tags, so that it will be stored in a database? I want to build a "live" CMS, similar to wordpress/webflow and using formatted `<input>` fields instead of `<p>`/`<h>` elements would make the html messy because, basically you would have to create two identical sites, one with normal text tags and the editable one with input fields, that look like normal text tags.

I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate reactive objects like `ref` to make it possible?

Alternatively you could create a site completely without normal text tags and instead use input field placeholders but that might mess up SEO.

Comment: What about using `:is` to change the `<p>` into `<input>` when in edit mode? Or you could have a sidebar or something where content is entered into, and the `<p>` tags content is updated in real-time, by binding it to the store's stage.

Comment: But in answer to your question, it is not possible for the user to directly edit a p tag.

Comment: @Lissy93 I'll check out `:is`. Thanks. Just to be clear, you mean the `CSS selector`?

Comment: @Lissy93 May I ask how one would change an html element into another using `:is`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the comment above using `:is` could work when switching between the states.

`<component :is="tag">`

`tag` value could be dynamic and depending on the `tag` value the component would change its state.

I would suggest using `div` with `v-html` that supports any markup when in `live` mode and when user is in `editing` mode display a rich text field. For rich text editing i would suggest to look at https://tiptap.dev/
you can bind the input value and the tiptap would create any html tags you need `<p/>, <li/>, <h1/>`

Comment: `<div>` element doesn't seem to work. Instead `<component>` should be used. It's an inherent vue component for managing `dynamic components`

Comment: yes, you are correct